Window Title Issue in My Plain Text Editor App on macOS developed with SwiftUI
I’m currently developing a plain text editor app that allows users to open, edit, and save files. However, I've encountered an issue with the window title management.
When I first open the app, the window title correctly displays "Untitled," which is what I want. However, if I close the app using the built-in close button in the upper left corner (instead of exiting the app), and then reopen it, the window title changes to the app's name instead of reverting to "Untitled."
Additionally, when I open a file, the window title changes to the app's name rather than the name of the file being opened.
Here’s the relevant portion of my code:
    import SwiftUI

    struct ContentView: View {
        @State private var text: String = ""
        @State private var currentFileURL: URL?
        @State private var windowTitle: String = "Untitled"

        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                TextEditor(text: $text)
                    .padding()
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 600, minHeight: 400)
            .onAppear {
                updateWindowTitle()
            }
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .openFile)) { _ in
                openFile()
            }
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .saveFile)) { _ in
                saveFile()
            }
        }

        func openFile() {
            let panel = NSOpenPanel()
            panel.allowedFileTypes = ["txt"]
            panel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
            panel.canChooseDirectories = false

            if panel.runModal() == .OK, let url = panel.url {
                do {
                    let fileContents = try String(contentsOf: url, encoding: .utf8)
                    self.text = fileContents
                    self.currentFileURL = url
                    updateWindowTitle(with: url)
                } catch {
                    print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        }

        func saveFile() {
            if let url = currentFileURL {
                do {
                    try text.write(to: url, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
                    updateWindowTitle(with: url)
                } catch {
                    print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            } else {
                let panel = NSSavePanel()
                panel.allowedFileTypes = ["txt"]
                panel.nameFieldStringValue = "new.txt"

                if panel.runModal() == .OK, let saveURL = panel.url {
                    do {
                        try text.write(to: saveURL, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
                        self.currentFileURL = saveURL
                        updateWindowTitle(with: saveURL)
                    } catch {
                        print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        func updateWindowTitle(with fileURL: URL? = nil) {
            let window = NSApplication.shared.windows.first
            if let url = fileURL {
                window?.title = url.lastPathComponent
            } else {
                window?.title = "Untitled"
            }
        }
    }

I would appreciate any guidance on how to ensure the window title behaves as expected—showing "Untitled" when no files are open, and displaying the file name when a file is opened.
Thank you for your help!
